# Conv net initialization

Tags: python, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

So I am working on gaining a deeper understanding of convolutional neural networks.  I am trying to set up my filters and am seriously confused as to how it works.  This is the purpose of the task, because I now know I don't understand how they work.

Here is a link to a gist of the full python script for initializing the first layer
https://gist.github.com/lhubbard01/68f1559f1c54f44f684d0ab99fd1e42f

and I'm using list comprehensions for stochastic initialization of feature maps.

```
def setup_layer(num_maps):
    maps = []
    for i in xrange(num_maps):
        maps.append(feature_map())
    return maps  #return the feature maps created for the first layer

def feature_map():
    #souds like the feature maps in each layer are nxn w neurons w a receptive field 
    # mxm, that take down important info?  but the stochastically init weights are the same in 
    # this 
    # nxn object? seems redundant.  What am i missing here?
    featmap_template = np.asarray([np.asarray([np.random.random() for i in xrange(3)]) for j in xrange(3)]) 
    featmap = np.asarray([np.asarray([featmap_template for k in xrange(28)]) for l in xrange(28)])
    return featmap
```

So obviously I'll have to look into the properties that also define it as a neural network down the line (forward-pass, backprop, activation) but right now I'm trying to get initialization correct.  I can see many redundancies in what I wrote, and perhaps I need to read the material a bit closer, but I figured some outside input from the stack exchange community would be constructive.

Comment: Do you understand basic neural networks? Just starting out with CNN's without basic understanding is not a viable approach. Ordinary fully-connected NN's also start with random weights.

Comment: Yeah I do somewhat get the basic concepts for basic neural networks. I just started in on Stanford's cs231 to go deeper into it. I'd be lying if I said I had a total understanding of it though so I'm going to spend a little more time with it